# php multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to form multidimensional array in with code...Something like that:

```
$data = array( 
    array( "Mike", "3" => 1, "4" => 0, "5" => 0), 
    array( "Steve", "3" => 0, "4" => 0, "5" => 0),
    array("John", "3" => 0, "4" => 0, "5" => 0),
     );
```

What code should be to get this result

```
 Array
(
[Mike] => Array
    (
        [3] => 1
        [4] => 0
        [5] => 0
    )

[Steve] => Array
    (
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 0
        [5] => 0
    )

[John] => Array
    (
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 0
        [5] => 0

    )
)
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this a code request or a question?

Comment: If it's a code request, the site you're looking for is elance.com or equivalent.

Comment: That you should write your own code and come to this place if you get stuck on something and ask a proper question on which we can give an answer that get's you going.

Answer (score 7):

```
$data = array( 
    "Mike" => array("3" => 1, "4" => 0, "5" => 0), 
    "Steve" => array("3" => 0, "4" => 0, "5" => 0),
    "John" => array("3" => 0, "4" => 0, "5" => 0),
     );
```

Like that?

A multidimensional array is just an array with another array as its value:

```
$array = array("key" => array("Array inside an array"));
```

Comment: No ... it gets diffrent result

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Mike] => Array
                (
                    [3] => 1
                    [4] => 0
                    [5] => 0
                )

        )

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = array( 
    "Mike"=>array("3" => 1, "4" => 0, "5" => 0), 
    "Steve"=>array("3" => 0, "4" => 0, "5" => 0),
    "John"=>array("3" => 0, "4" => 0, "5" => 0),
);
```

Comment: That's it thanks... How can I acces to "Mike" and how to acces to Mike's first element (3=>1)?

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = array( 
    "Mike" => array(3 => 1, 4 => 0, 5 => 0), 
    "Steve" => array(3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0),
    "John" => array(3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0)
);
```

Comment: That's it thanks... How can I acces to "Mike" and how to acces to Mike's first element (3=>1)?

Comment: $data["Mike"] and $data["Mike"][3]

Comment: if I write   foreach($data as $row)   I only get array of numbers... How do I get "Mike"?

Comment: I got it... foreach($data as $key=>$name)